# Constructor Definition

Tags: c++, constructor

Ok so i have a class Vector:

```
#include <cstdlib>

class Vec
{
private:
    size_t size;
    int * ptab;

public:
    Vec(size_t n);
    ~Vec() {delete [] ptab;}

    size_t size() const {return size;}
    int & operator[](int n) {return ptab[n];}
    int operator[](int n) const {return ptab[n];}

    void operator=(Vec const& v);
};

inline Vec::Vec(size_t n) : size(n), ptab(new int[n])
{ }
```

and the problem is that in one of my homework exercises i have to extend constructor def, so all elements will be initialized with zeros. I thought i know the basics but cant get through this dynamic array  -.-

ps. sry for gramma and other mistakes ;)

Answer (score 10):

In a *new-expression* you can use a pair of parentheses as an initializer to *value-initialize* (which for an array of `int` zero-initializes every element) an object.

```
new int[n]()
```

Other points:

- As your user-defined destructor deallocates a dynamically allocated array you need a user-defined copy constructor to ensure that your class is easy to use safely.
- Your copy assignment operator should have a return type of `Vec&`, not `void` and return `*this` to conform with common conventions and to work with standard container templates.
- You should consider declaring the single parameter constructor `explicit` unless you really want to enable implicit conversions from `size_t` to `Vec`.

Comment: how common is that `explicit` rule?

Comment: @7vies: I'm not quite sure what you mean, there's no specific rule that I know of concerning use of `explicit`.

Comment: sorry, I mean how commonly would people define constructors explicit by default, like some/most/all experienced programmers do that?

Comment: @7vies: I believe that single parameter constructors (including constructors with at most one non-optional parameter) should be made `explicit` unless there is good reason not to. I don't know about other programmers, but in any code that I write or review single parameter constructors are (and should be) `explicit` far more often than they aren't.